# Ban IP by country in UFW

Tags: 12.10, firewall, ufw

I want to block a country in my server, but I don't know which rule I must use in UFW (or iptables). For example, people from US and other countries can see the site, but visitors from Russia can't. Can somebody explain to me how I can ban by country in UFW?

**My server Details**
• Ubuntu 12.10
• Nginx
• phpfpm
• Mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this nice script that automatically will block IPs by country in Iptables:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: Block all traffic from RUSSIA (ru) and BELARUS (by). Use ISO code. #
# See url for more info - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/?p=3402
# Author: nixCraft <www.cyberciti.biz> under GPL v.2.0+
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISO="ru by"

### Set PATH ###
IPT=/sbin/iptables
WGET=/usr/bin/wget
EGREP=/bin/egrep

### No editing below ###
SPAMLIST="countrydrop"
ZONEROOT="/root/iptables"
DLROOT="http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries"

cleanOldRules(){
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -F
$IPT -t mangle -X
$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
}

# create a dir
[ ! -d $ZONEROOT ] && /bin/mkdir -p $ZONEROOT

# clean old rules
cleanOldRules

# create a new iptables list
$IPT -N $SPAMLIST

for c  in $ISO
do
    # local zone file
    tDB=$ZONEROOT/$c.zone

    # get fresh zone file
    $WGET -O $tDB $DLROOT/$c.zone

    # country specific log message
    SPAMDROPMSG="$c Country Drop"

    # get 
    BADIPS=$(egrep -v "^#|^$" $tDB)
    for ipblock in $BADIPS
    do
       $IPT -A $SPAMLIST -s $ipblock -j LOG --log-prefix "$SPAMDROPMSG"
       $IPT -A $SPAMLIST -s $ipblock -j DROP
    done
done

# Drop everything 
$IPT -I INPUT -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I OUTPUT -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I FORWARD -j $SPAMLIST

# call your other iptable script
# /path/to/other/iptables.sh

exit 0
```

Source and more info: [Linux Iptables Just Block By Country](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/).

Comment: You should have a look at the [data this uses](http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/)... The UK has one IP block and many countries have none. It's flawed beyond use.

Comment: @Oli I observed this, but I thought that I have a problem. Maybe it's a temporary issue, because I see that the article from the source it was updated recently. Anyway, the script is not bad and it can be adapted to be useful. Maybe I will think later about this.

Comment: I found another way http://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker

Comment: @VahidNameni I had a look at http://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker.  Their lists are far from complete.  I used an online IP checker to find 10 different addresses appearing from China in my auth.log.  I then looked up those 10 in the Visitor Blocker file for China.  Only 1 in 10 matched.